# Finite groups $G$ such that the primes dividing $|G|$ are exactly the primes dividing $|G^{ab}|$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a classification of finite groups $G$ with the property that any prime dividing $|G|$ must also divide $|G^{ab}|$ (the order of its abelianization)?

Being nilpotent is sufficient, though not necessary. On the other hand, being supersolvable is not sufficient, since the abelianization of any dihedral group $D_{2k}$ is a 2-group, and is also not necessary.

Are there other interesting families of finite groups which have this property?

(In particular I'm interested in groups generated by 2 elements)

Comment: The group $G$ need not be solvable. One example is $G = A_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Or similarly, for ay finite group $H$ of order $n,$ the group $G = H \times \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \right)$ would have order $n^{2}$ and Abelianization of order divisible by $n$, so there is no hope of a classification without further restrictions.

Comment: Hmmm good points... Though, I am only really interested in groups generated by 2 elements, do you think that amongst these groups there might be an interesting classification?

Comment: As a note - Jeremy Rouse's group can be generated by 2 elements. $A_5$ can be generated by an element $a$ of order 3 and an element $b$ of order 5, and $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$ can be generated by 5 and 6. Then $(a, 6), (b, 5)$ generate $(0, 18), (0, 25), (a^2, 0), (b, 0)$, and so generate the whole group. More generally, any finite group $H$ generated by two elements of coprime order leads to $G = H \times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ satisfying your condition in a similar manner.

Comment: A tempting restriction would be to find a class of groups with the requested condition, which is also stable under taking quotients and subgroups. But then it can be checked that it would consists of nilpotent groups.

Comment: Take a 2 generated group $H$ of order $n$ and consider $G'= H\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The free group $F$ on two generators maps into $G'$ whose projections are surjective. The image $G$ of $F$, has the property that it is two generated, maps onto $H$ and also has abelianization maping onto $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. So, a classification, even for two generated groups seems hopeless.

Comment: @Venkataramana - all that says is that every finite group is a quotient of a group with this property, right? Why should that be an obstacle to classification?

Comment: @user44191 it's a bit heuristic, but because it's hard, if not practically impossible, to give nice families of finite groups such that admit all finite groups as quotients... except trivialities such as "the family of all finite groups" or variants. By "nice" family I would mean a list of "nice groups". [In contrast to the fact that every finite group embeds into some alternating group, for instance.]

Comment: When $H$ is a finite group and $n$ is just the product of all primes which divide $|H|$ but not $|H^{ab}|$, then $G= H\times C_n$ has the property in question. If $H$ is $2$-generated, then so is $G$.